# Configure zeromq.node req cache

Tags: node.js, sockets, configuration, zeromq

When using zeromq from c, req sockets don't allow sending twice.
Now, zeromq.node allows to keep on sending, so I'm assuming zeromq.node caches additional messages internally and waits for an answer before submitting the next.

This code demonstrates this behavior:

```
var zmq = require('zmq');
var req = zmq.socket('req');
var router = zmq.socket('router');
var tcp = 'tcp://127.0.0.1:3000';

router.on('message', function(source, _, command, data) {
    router.send([source, '', data]); // pass through
});

req.connect(tcp).on('message', function(data) {
    console.log('receive: ' + data); // acknowledge
});

var i = 0;
while(i < 100)
    req.send(['REQ', ++i]); // saved in cache and send later, on bindSync

setTimeout(router.bindSync.bind(router, tcp), 1000);
```

This cache seems to have no limit and can fill the entire memory.

Is there a way to configure it or to limit it to a certain number of items/retries?

Comment: `req.setsockopt(zmq.ZMQ_HWM, 10)` should configure the socket to queue only 10 items for each peer it's connected to. I can't try whether it works since I don't have node at the computer I'm present at, but you might give it a shot so we see if it really works?

Comment: @Mjh your idea seems great, but req.setsockopt throws an error (line 246, invalid argument on _zmq.setsocket) as if the underlying code wasn't expecting this method. My installed version is the latest: 4.0.5.

Comment: The options changed in ZMQ 4.0, you should be using [ZMQ_SNDHWM](http://api.zeromq.org/4-0:zmq-setsockopt)

Comment: @Jason thanks ;-) but this flag only configure libzmq, the node req inner cache do not seems to be configurable :-(

Comment: hm, yeah, that makes sense, in this circumstance it *would* be being cached before it even gets to ZMQ... looks like a bug to me.  You should be able to tell it how to behave in these circumstances, you may not want that extra "security"